# $p^2=p\in \bar{I}$, I ideal of Banach algebra $\Rightarrow p\in I$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, ideals, banach-algebras

Let $I\subset A$ be a ideal of a Banach algebra $A$. Assume $p\in \overline I$ and $p^2=p$.

Show: $p\in I$.

Can someone give me a little hint how to solve this, please?

Comment: Being complete is the only hypothesis you have on $A$ ? How is its norm ?

Comment: Well, I have that $A$ is a Banach algebra. What do you mean by "How is its norm?" ?

Comment: Is it an algebra over some complete field at least ? So it's a norm, but is it multiplicative or only sub-multiplicative ?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra.
It is a Banach algebra over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. For the norm we have $\|x y\| \leq \|x\| \|y\|$.

Comment: There are Banach algebras over anything, over any Banach ring in fact, like $\mathbf{Z}$ or $\mathbf{Z}_p$ ($p$-adic integers) or $\mathbf{Q}(( T ))$, or, why not, over $\mathbf{F}_p$. This wikipedia's article is not accurate at all.

Comment: Okay, sorry. Since I haven't heard of these algebras so far, I thought my language is clear. Is it at least precise enough now?

Comment: Yeah, no worries ! Now it's clear.

Comment: Last question : obviously your algebra is not necessarily commutative, but is it unital ?

Comment: Not nec. commutative and not necessarily unital, but it should not make a big difference, whether it is unital, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is recorded as Lemma 2.7 in

> Niels Jakob Laustsen, Thomas Schlumprecht, and András Zsák, [The lattice of closed ideals in the Banach algebra of operators on a certain dual Banach space](http://eprints.lancs.ac.uk/21078/1/ideals_in_ell_1_sum_of_ell_2n.pdf), J. Operator Theory 56 (2006), no. 2, 391–402.

I assume that $A$ is unital, if not, we can pass to the unitisation.

Suppose that $(t_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence in $I$ that converges to an idempotent $p$. Since $pAp$ is a Banach algebra with identity $p$ and $pt_np \to p^3=p$, there exists $n$ so that $pt_np$ is invertible in $pAp$. Consequently, $p = (psp)(pt_np)$ for some $s\in A$. This proves that $p\in I$.